# How to change one part of a string taken from C line argument?

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to write a simple backup program. It will take in a file and then create a file with the same content, with a .bak extension unless specified. Below is my code, my program run fine when I specify that I want .back extension for my new file. I'm having problem trying to read in the path in the command line, truncate the file extension, concatenate .back to it. Can someone point out the problems in my code? thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char ch, buffer[256];
    FILE *source, *target;

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Source file must be specified.");   
    }
    else if (argc == 3)
    {
        source = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
        target = fopen(argv[2], "wb");

        while ((ch = fgetc(source)) != EOF)
        {
            fputc(ch, target);
        }
    }

// the part below doesn't work
    else if (argc == 1)
    {
        int length = 0;
        source = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
        strcpy_s(buffer, 256, argv[1]);
        length = strlen(argv[1]) - 1;
        while (length > 0)
        {
            if (buffer[length] == ".")
                break;
            length--;
        }
        buffer[length + 1] = '\0';
        strcat(buffer, "bak");
        target = fopen(buffer, "wb");
        while ((ch = fgetc(source)) != EOF)
        {
            fputc(ch, target);
        }
    }

    fclose(source);
    fclose(target);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If argc is 1, does it make any sense to look at argv[1]?

Comment: You may be happy to hear there is a function to scan backwards for a character: [`strrchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strrchr). Also, better consider what happens when your user supplies a filename *without* extension. In that case you need to stop when encountering a path separator: the forward or backward slash and the `:`.

Comment: @Jongware any suggestion on how to deal with filename without extension? I tried to check the string for '.' character. Then concatenate a ".bak" after not finding any '.' . However it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be trying to modify `argv[1]` when you didn't allocate it. That sounds like a recipe for disaster, as your longer string may not fit the allocation.

Also, you are only running this code if `argc == 1`. If `argc == 1` then the last argument is `argv[0]` not `argv[1]`. I think you want `if (argc == 2)`.

A suggestion (untested):

```
const char *suffix = ".bak";
char *fn = malloc (strlen(argv[1]) + strlen (suffix) + 1);
strcpy (fn, argv[1])
char *dot = strrchr (fn, '.');
if (dot)
    *dot = '\0';
strcpy (fn + strlen(fn), suffix);
/* ... do some stuff with fn ... */
free (fn);
```

Comment: @PaulRooney I'd thought that was obvious, but perhaps not - edited

Comment: what type of value is fn?

Comment: `fn` is 1 `char` too small.

Comment: @chux: indeed, if there is no dot at al. Thanks - fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I think the main confusion is with your handling of command line arguments.

When you do

```
if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Source file must be specified.");   
    }
```

it means

```
else if (argc == 1) { .... }
```

Can never run, 1 is less than 2 of course.

The best action to take is to return if `argc` is less than 2 (i.e. you passed no command line arguments). This prevents the `fcloses` at the end causing a crash (or undefined behaviour). Even better move the closes inside the if blocks or assign NULL to your FILE pointers intially and check for NULL before closing them.

Where you check `argc == 1` it should be `argc == 2`. If argc is 1 it means you got no command line arguments, as the first argument is the name of the executable.

Note also this line is wrong

```
if (buffer[length] == ".")
```

It should be

```
if (buffer[length] == '.')
```

You are comparing a character, not a string (ultimately a pointer) and you should get a warning here (compare integer to pointer).